# Mailgun: 'to' parameter is not a valid address

Tags: python, mailgun

I am using a for loop to schedule sending some emails using Mailgun. The first email gets a 200 response and is sent correctly. but the 3 remaining emails all get a 400 response with the following error `'to' parameter is not a valid address. please check documentation"`. I'm totally stumped. I've singled out everything and all appears to be correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def indoctrination(email, name):
    requests.post('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/{}@{}/members'.format(list, domain_url),
            auth=auth,
            data={'subscribed': True,
                  'address': email,
                  'name': name})
    for x in range(1,5):
        if x > 1:
            days = x - 1
            time = datetime.utcnow() #+ timedelta(days=days)
        else:
            time = datetime.utcnow()
        subject = ['Welcome to Python Financial', 'Notes and Pizza', 'Your questions answered', 'Why are we not doing this?']
        email = requests.post('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/{}/messages'.format(domain_url),
                auth=auth,
                data={"from": from_email,
                      "to": '{} <{}>'.format(name, email),
                      "subject": "{}".format(subject[x-1]),
                      "html": open("templates/email{}.html".format(x)),
                      "o:deliverytime": time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000")})
        print 'Response status code: ', email.status_code
        print 'Data: ', email.json()
```

Comment: What a stupid mistake I made. When I pass 'email' into the function I then changed the variable to create the message so I wasn't inputting a valid email address in the 'to:' field. The problem was simply fixed by renaming the email variable within the function.

Comment: Is this question really worth keeping? You made a typo. I don't think anyone is going to learn anything from this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

See comment. Just renamed the email variable to fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you are came here from same error in `Laravel`, please, check if you are using `Mailable` class in `Notification`. `Laravel` will not automatically substitute `email` from `$notifiable` in such case and you'll get this error. You'll need to specify `to` parameter or  use `MailMessage` which will work nice in such case.